# Laravel Dynamic Dependent Dropdown

Tags: laravel, forms

I need to add a Laravel Dynamic Dependent Dropdown. Im confused..
In my database, i have both categories and their childrens.

- Account_id =0  => Categorie
- Account_id =1 => Sub Categorie of  category or subcategory with id =1
- Account_id =2 => Sub categorie of  category or subcategory with id =2

This is my actual code :

Method:

```
 public function index()
 {
    $categories = Account::where('account_id', '=', 0)->get();
    $allCategories = Account::where('account_id', '=', 0)- 
  >pluck('account_name','id');
     return view('Account.list',compact('categories', 'allCategories')); // 
  set the path of you templates file.

  }

public function children(Request $request)
{
    return Account::where('account_id', $request->account_id)->pluck('account_name', 'id');
}
```

View:

```
                                 <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('account_id', 'Parent Category:')!!}
     {!! Form::select('account_id', $allCategories,  ['placeholder' => 
     'Choose Category'])!!}
        </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('children', 'Child category:')!!}
     {!! Form::select('children', [], null, ['placeholder' => 'Choose child 
     category'])!!}
    </div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/categories', [
   'uses' => 'AccountController@index',
   'as' => 'categories'
 ]);
 Route::get('/categories/children', [
   'uses' => 'AccountController@children',
   'as' => 'categories.children'
 ]);
```

JS:

```
 <script>
$('#account_id').change(function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.value;
    $.get('/categories/children?account_id=' + account_id, function(data) {
        $('#children').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            var option = $("<option></option>")
                  .attr("value", key)                         
                  .text(value);

            $('#children').append(option);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: put `dd($allCategories)` and tell me what return

Comment: It returns all my categories in my database which they have all of them account_id=0. But they can have subcategories(childrens) so i need to select them in another select form .

Comment: ahh ok you need apply `javascript` when select first other `childrem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this first create new `route`

```
Route::post('subchildren/youcontroller', [
  'as'   => 'children.categories',
  'uses' => 'youUrlController\yourController@childrenCategory',
]);
```

next create `route` go to `controller` create new `method`

```
public function childrenCategory(Request $request) 
{
   try {
     $subCategory= subCategory::where('category_id', $request->nameSelectCategoryinYourView)->get();
      return response()->json(['subCategory' => $subCategory], 200);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'Error'], 403);
  }
}
```

next in your `view`

```
<div class="form-group  m-b-40">
  <select name="subCategory" class="form-control p-0" id='subCategory'></select>
</div>
```

next in your `javascript`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#FirstSelect').change(function () {
    $('#subCategory').empty();
    var Category = $(this).val();

    datos = {
      tipo : Category
    },

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ route('children.categories') }}',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      data: datos,
      success: function (argument) {

        arreglo = {id:"a", tipo:""};
        argument.detalles.unshift(arreglo); 

        $.each(argument.subCategory, function(index, el) {

          var opcion = '<option value="'+ el.id +'">'+ el.subCategoryName+'</option>';
          $('#subCategory').append( opcion );
        });
      }
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
  })
 });
});
```

Comment: thank you, please can you edit and add also the first form which select category ? i dont know what i need to write in nameSelectCategoryinYourView and what my category form would be

Comment: you need create other select for print sub Categorys

Comment: Yes sir, i did. But what will be my code for select category  please ?

Comment: code for select category send for `request` other `method` search for id you select

Comment: ` $('#FirstSelect').change` this you put id first select and next on `var Category = $(this).val();` you pass `value to ajax and search subCategory`

Comment: Select form is empty for categories and sub categories, please check out my eddited post to see my modification.

Comment: why you not display pluck you categories??

Comment: you not send value on first select you need pss categorys in your first method display your categories

Comment: Sir, i changed the code, now i have my categories in the categories select. But  subCategory is not workign. please check out my eddited post

Comment: wheh you change select get id?? put `console.log(var Category = $(this).val();)`

Comment: no sir.. I eddited all my code, so you can see what i did there

Comment: put in your `javascript` down `var Category` `console.log(Category);` and press F12 in your inspect when change you first select tell me if print `id` on you console

Comment: There is nothing in the console sir

Comment: try this `javascript` put all method change inside `document.ready`

Comment: I think sir the probleme is from my post subcategory route.  Is that correct ?

Comment: Apparently no, nothing is happening

Comment: you need check why not trigger event this event need execute or not work

Comment: This code is working for me but i can't adapt it to my case : 
https://gist.github.com/edomaru/aae9eb836a9a6390d4decb71e5c97ebf

They use parent  instead of account_id
And null instead of =0 

Can you help me to adapt it please ?

Comment: thie methos is same you need adapt with you show me if your console not display eror when you change event trigger

Comment: Sir, i have changed some code and now it print me something in console. Please check out my eddited post. 
Everytime i select new category, In my console : 
http://localhost:8000/categories/children?account_id=[object%20HTMLSelectElement] and it print all categories